# Windows 10 - Two-drive JBOD with dedicated parity drive for third?

Tags: windows-10, nas, storage, jbod

I'm moving to a standalone Windows 10 Pro install because unRAID VM was not playing well with my hardware. My goal was to have two 2tb drives acting as a JBOD with a third 2tb drive acting as a parity drive between the two. However, looking at Windows Storage Spaces, it seems that the parity option is striped (and has terrible write performance).

Are there any other Windows-based solutions that can accomplish this? The parity does not have to be calculated and written on the JBOD write. A nightly sync or something along those lines would do nicely.

Answer (score 0):

For only 3 physical disks your only looking for RAID5 which you can use.

I've been looking for a way to use a JBOD + Parity on other systems like unRAID uses but have come up short. Let me know if you found anything useful.